# What are the benefits of currying?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

I don't think I quite understand currying, since I'm unable to see any massive benefit it could provide. Perhaps someone could enlighten me with an example demonstrating why it is so useful. Does it truly have benefits and applications, or is it just an over-appreciated concept?

Comment: Besides making your food exceptional, I believe it is used to allow chaining of operations on a data set. The result is that instead of needing to write complex algorithms with nested loops, etc, you can accomplish it with a few simple commands.

Comment: Do you understand the benefits of lambda functions?

Comment: @Shmiddty you would still need a loop though, so that you could control how many times you appended on the next "curry"?

Comment: Do you understand the point of partial application, and are just asking what specific advantages currying adds, or do you not get partial application either? Also, are you asking for practical advantages (things you can do more easily) or theoretical advantages (ways currying can make languages simpler, facilitate proofs, etc.)?

Comment: practical advantages. As I understand it, instead of a = b + c, you can do something like add(a,b), c?

Comment: It seems that you're not entirely clear on what "currying" specifically means, which is understandable given that the term is often misused in odd ways, so it might help if you more clearly describe what you're asking for examples of. For instance, if you can see why partial application is useful, currying makes using it easier; but if you've seen the term "currying" misused to *mean* partial application, that's a very different question!

Comment: If you're asking about the benefits of partial application (or the benefit of currying with regard thereto), I think the answer is that there's not a "massive benefit".  Instead, there are a myriad of small to medium benefits that occur in a myriad of places in your code, until suddenly the whole concept seems obvious and necessary, and working without it is a pain.  (The benefit of currying *per se* is that it renders that myriad of myriads slightly easier.)  So you may not get the sort of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(There is a slight difference between *currying* and *partial application*, although they're closely related; since they're often mixed together, I'll deal with both terms.)

The place where I realized the benefits first was when I saw sliced operators:

```
incElems = map (+1)
--non-curried equivalent: incElems = (\elems -> map (\i -> (+) 1 i) elems)
```

IMO, this is totally easy to read. Now, if the type of `(+)` was `(Int,Int) -> Int` *, which is the uncurried version, it would (counter-intuitively) result in an error -- but curryied, it works as expected, and has type `[Int] -> [Int]`.

You mentioned C# lambdas in a comment. In C#, you could have written `incElems` like so, given a function `plus`:

```
var incElems = xs => xs.Select(x => plus(1,x))
```

If you're used to point-free style, you'll see that the `x` here is redundant. Logically, that code could be reduced to

```
var incElems = xs => xs.Select(curry(plus)(1))
```

which is awful due to the lack of automatic partial application with C# lambdas. And that's the crucial point to decide where currying is actually useful: mostly when it happens *implicitly*. For me, `map (+1)` is the easiest to read, then comes `.Select(x => plus(1,x))`, and the version with `curry` should probably be avoided, if there is no really good reason.

Now, if readable, the benefits sum up to *shorter, more readable and less cluttered code* -- unless there is some abuse of point-free style done is with it (I do love `(.).(.)`, but it is... special)

Also, lambda calculus would get impossible without using curried functions, since it has only one-valued (but therefor higher-order) functions.

<sub>* Of course it actually in `Num`, but it's more readable like this for the moment.</sub>

---

Update: how currying actually works.

Look at the type of `plus` in C#:

```
int plus(int a, int b) {..}
```

You have to give it *a tuple* of values -- not in C# terms, but mathematically spoken; you can't just leave out the second value. In haskell terms, that's

```
plus :: (Int,Int) -> Int,
```

which could be used like

```
incElem = map (\x -> plus (1, x)) -- equal to .Select (x => plus (1, x))
```

That's way too much characters to type. Suppose you'd want to do this more often in the future. Here's a little helper:

```
curry f = \x -> (\y -> f (x,y))
plus' = curry plus
```

which gives

```
incElem = map (plus' 1)
```

Let's apply this to a concrete value.

```
incElem [1] 
= (map (plus' 1)) [1]
= [plus' 1 1]
= [(curry plus) 1 1]
= [(\x -> (\y -> plus (x,y))) 1 1]
= [plus (1,1)]
= [2]
```

Here you can see `curry` at work. It turns a standard haskell style function application (`plus' 1 1`) into a call to a "tupled" function -- or, viewed at a higher level, transforms the "tupled" into the "untupled" version.

Fortunately, most of the time, you don't have to worry about this, as there is automatic partial application.

Comment: Just to clarify, why is (+1) currying? I just want to be sure I understand exactly what it is, not just why it is good. Thanks

Comment: @user997112: `(+ 1)` is partial application, using a special syntax for infix operators. If `(+)` were called `add` instead, currying would let you write `add 1 1` instead of `add (1, 1)`. Partially applying the latter is much more awkward, as the above answer explains.

Comment: @user997112 - `(+1)` is partial application - `(+)` is a curried function since it has type `Int -> Int -> Int` instead of `(Int, Int) -> Int` as it does in C# for example. In Haskell you can convert `(+)` to the second form using `uncurry` e.g. uncurry (+) $ (1,1)

Comment: @user997112 I've added an example.

Answer (score 7):

It's not the best thing since sliced bread, but if you're using lambdas anyway, it's easier to use higher-order functions without using lambda syntax.  Compare:

```
map (max 4) [0,6,9,3] --[4,6,9,4]
map (\i -> max 4 i) [0,6,9,3] --[4,6,9,4]
```

These kinds of constructs come up often enough when you're using functional programming, that it's a nice shortcut to have and lets you think about the problem from a slightly higher level--you're mapping against the "`max 4`" function, not some random function that happens to be defined as `(\i -> max 4 i)`.  It lets you start to think in higher levels of indirection more easily:

```
let numOr4 = map $ max 4
let numOr4' = (\xs -> map (\i -> max 4 i) xs)
numOr4 [0,6,9,3] --ends up being [4,6,9,4] either way; 
                 --which do you think is easier to understand?
```

That said, it's not a panacea; sometimes your function's parameters will be the wrong order for what you're trying to do with currying, so you'll have to resort to a lambda anyway.  However, once you get used to this style, you start to learn how to design your functions to work well with it, and once those neurons starts to connect inside your brain, previously complicated constructs can start to seem obvious in comparison.

Comment: Oh, you never *have* to resort to a lambda (but you often should).

Comment: I dont understand that comment?

Comment: @user997112 you can use `flip` and friends to create new functions from existing functions, with the order of the parameters changed.  So if you've got `f::x->y->z`, `(flip f) y1` would be equivalent to `(\x -> f x y1)`, which allows you to "curry" the 2nd parameter.  But this can (usually does) end up producing code far more obscure than just using a lambda.

Comment: In a word: readability.  Using unnecessary lambdas can make your expressions hard to read; judicious use of partial application and functions like `flip` can improve on this.  However, taking this to an extreme (by eliminating all lambdas, which it turns out is always *possible*...) can also make your program unreadable.

Answer (score 4):

One benefit of currying is that it allows partial application of functions without the need of any special syntax/operator. A simple example:

```
mapLength = map length
mapLength ["ab", "cde", "f"]
>>> [2, 3, 1]
mapLength ["x", "yz", "www"]
>>> [1, 2, 3]

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
length :: [a] -> Int
mapLength :: [[a]] -> [Int]
```

The `map` function can be considered to have type `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])` because of currying, so when `length` is applied as its first argument, it yields the function `mapLength` of type `[[a]] -> [Int]`.

Comment: Which part of your code is the currying? Do you mean the definition of map (or length) contains it within prelude?

Comment: @user997112 `map` is a curried function. That's why it's possible to write `map length` to partially apply it (as opposed to `\xs -> map (length, xs)`, which you'd have to write if it was defined using tuples rather than currying).

Comment: @user997112 Clarified in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Currying has the convenience features mentioned in other answers, but it also often serves to simplify reasoning about the language or to implement some code much easier than it could be otherwise.  For example, currying means that any function at all has a type that's compatible with `a ->b`.  If you write some code whose type involves `a -> b`, that code can be made work with any function at all, no matter how many arguments it takes.

The best known example of this is the `Applicative` class:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure  :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

And an example use:

```
-- All possible products of numbers taken from [1..5] and [1..10]
example = pure (*) <*> [1..5] <*> [1..10]
```

In this context, `pure` and `<*>` adapt any function of type `a -> b` to work with lists of type `[a]`.  Because of partial application, this means you can also adapt functions of type `a -> b -> c` to work with `[a]` and `[b]`, or `a -> b -> c -> d` with `[a]`, `[b]` and `[c]`, and so on.

The reason this works is because `a -> b -> c` is the same thing as `a -> (b -> c)`:

```
(+)                             :: Num a => a -> a -> a
pure (+)                        :: (Applicative f, Num a) => f (a -> a -> a)
[1..5], [1..10]                 :: Num a => [a]
pure (+) <*> [1..5]             :: Num a => [a -> a]
pure (+) <*> [1..5] <*> [1..10] :: Num a => [a]
```

Another, different use of currying is that Haskell allows you to partially apply type constructors.  E.g., if you have this type:

```
data Foo a b = Foo a b
```

...it actually makes sense to write `Foo a` in many contexts, for example:

```
instance Functor (Foo a) where
    fmap f (Foo a b) = Foo a (f b)
```

I.e., `Foo` is a two-parameter type constructor with kind `* -> * -> *`; `Foo a`, the partial application of `Foo` to just one type, is a type constructor with kind `* -> *`.  `Functor` is a type class that can only be instantiated for type constrcutors of kind `* -> *`.  Since `Foo a` is of this kind, you can make a `Functor` instance for it.

Comment: Good point. I think that's what I tried to say about the lambda calculus: currying allows you to use a language which only supports single-valued functions as if it had multi-valued functions.

Comment: @phg, so do uncurried (i.e. tupled) functions.

Answer (score 3):

The "no-currying" form of partial application works like this:

- We have a function `f : (A ✕ B) → C`
- We'd like to apply it partially to some `a : A`
- To do this, we build a closure out of `a` and `f` (we don't evaluate `f` at all, for the time being)
- Then some time later, we receive the second argument `b : B`
- Now that we have both the `A` and `B` argument, we can evaluate `f` in its original form...
- So we recall `a` from the closure, and evaluate `f(a,b)`.

A bit complicated, isn't it?

When `f` is curried in the first place, it's rather simpler:

- We have a function `f : A → B → C`
- We'd like to apply it partially to some `a : A` – which we can just *do*: `f a`
- Then some time later, we receive the second argument `b : B`
- We apply the already evaluated `f a` to `b`.

So far so nice, but more important than being simple, this also gives us extra possibilities for implementing our function: we may be able to do some calculations as soon as the `a` argument is received, and these calculations won't need to be done later, even if the function is evaluated with multiple different `b` arguments!

To give an example, consider [this audio filter](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/timed-media/blob/master/Media/Timed/Audio/FX/Filter/SimpleIIR.hs#L208), an *infinite impulse response* filter. It works like this: for each audio sample, you feed an "accumulator function" (`f`) with some state parameter (in this case, a simple number, 0 at the beginning) and the audio sample. The function then does some magic, and spits out the *new* internal state<sup>1</sup> and the output sample.

Now here's the crucial bit – what kind of magic the function does depends on the coefficient<sup>2</sup> `λ`, which is not quite a constant: it depends both on what cutoff frequency we'd like the filter to have (this governs "how the filter will sound") and on what sample rate we're processing in. Unfortunately, the calculation of `λ` is a bit more complicated (`lp1stCoeff $ 2*pi * (νᵥ ~*% δs)` than the rest of the magic, so we wouldn't like having to do this for every single sample, all over again. Quite annoying, because `νᵥ` and `δs` are *almost* constant: they change very seldom, certainly not at each audio sample.

But currying saves the day! We simply calculate `λ` as soon as we have the necessary parameters. Then, at each of the many many audio samples to come, we only need to perform the remaining, very easy magic: `yⱼ = yⱼ₁ + λ ⋅ (xⱼ - yⱼ₁)`. So we're being efficient, and still keeping a nice safe referentially transparent purely-functional interface.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this kind of state-passing can generally be done more nicely with the `State` or `ST` monad, that's just not particularly beneficial in this example

<sup>2</sup> Yes, this is a lambda symbol. I hope I'm not confusing anybody – fortunately, in Haskell it's clear that *lambda functions* are written with `\`, not with `λ`.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat dubious to ask what the benefits of currying are without specifying the context in which you're asking the question:

- In some cases, like functional languages, currying will merely be seen as something that has a more local change, where you could replace things with explicit tupled domains.  However, this isn't to say that currying is useless in these languages.  In some sense, programming with curried functions make you "feel" like you're programming in a more functional style, because you more typically face situations where you're dealing with higher order functions.  Certainly, most of the time, you will "fill in" all of the arguments to a function, but in the cases where you want to use the function in its partially applied form, this is a bit simpler to do in curried form.  We typically tell our beginning programmers to use this when learning a functional language just because it feels like better style and reminds them they're programming in more than just C.  Having things like `curry` and `uncurry` also help for certain conveniences within functional programming languages too, I can think of arrows within Haskell as a specific example of where you would use `curry` and `uncurry` a bit to apply things to different pieces of an arrow, etc...
- In some cases, you want to think about more than functional programs, you can present currying / uncurrying as a way to state the elimination and introduction rules for and in constructive logic, which provides a connection to a more elegant motivation for why it exists.
- In some cases, for example, in Coq, using curried functions versus tupled functions can produce different induction schemes, which may be easier or harder to work with, depending on your applications.

Answer (score 1):

I used to think that currying was simple syntax sugar that saves you a bit of typing. For example, instead of writing

```
(\ x -> x + 1)
```

I can merely write

```
(+1)
```

The latter is instantly more readable, and less typing to boot.

So if it's just a convenient short cut, why all the fuss?

Well, it turns out that because function types are curried, you can write code which is polymorphic in the number of arguments a function has.

For example, the `QuickCheck` framework lets you test functions by feeding them randomly-generated test data. It works on any function who's input type can be auto-generated. But, because of currying, the authors were able to rig it so this works with *any number of arguments*. Were functions *not* curried, there would be a different testing function for each number of arguments - and that would just be tedious.